# How to interpret --revision in svn2git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, revision

I'm using [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) for some migration.
Our SVN repo has around the 15000 revisions but only the last 2000 revisions are very important for our developers.

So I want to use the `--revision` to define the revisions:

```
$ svn2git ... --revision 13000:HEAD ..
```

Now is my question: How do I have to interpret the migration of this?
Is everything before the revision 13000 also in my git but just without commits/tags/ or is this revision really the start and is all the data before this commit gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `svn2git <SVN URL> --revision 13000:HEAD --username name`, it will migrate svn revision from revision `13000` to current revision. The revisions before `13000` is not exist in the migration git repo (including commits, tags, and branches). You can also check in `.git/svn/refs/remotes/origin`, you will find it only contains tags and branches from revision `13000` to current revision.

If you want to keep branches and tags from svn to git, you can use `--tags` and `--branches` options.

Comment: but all the data will still be there in the last revisions? (because it's builded on those old revisions). I will only miss the branch/commit/tag stuff?

Comment: No, git only contains the revisions you specified. Assume you have a file `test.txt` in revisions before `13000`, but you deleted the file in revision `13000`, when you migrate revisions `13000:HEAD`, you will not find `test.txt` in git.